# Custom Action failing to execute during installation created with Installshield 16

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation, installshield

I have run this custom action with Installshield Limited Edition for Visual Studio in the past and it has worked. But now when I try this with Installshield 2016, this custom action gives me a 1722 error and rolls back the installation. The log file doesn't give any more detail than "failed with error 1..." and the 1722 error.

My custom action setup via the Wizard -

Working Dir: InstallDir

FileName & Command Line: "[SystemFolder]cmd.exe" /c "[INSTALLDIR]somefilename.exe" "'%r' '%keyname=keyname' '%keydll=some.dll' '%appexe=[INSTALLDIR]differentfilename.exe'"

What this is supposed to do is run somefilename.exe from the command line, with parameters "%r", "%keyname", "%keydll" & "%appexe".

When I run it on the command line directly so - 
"C:\Program Files (x86)"\somefilename.exe "%r" "%keyname=keyname" "%keydll=some.dll" "%appexe=C:\Program Files (x86)\differentfilename.exe" - it runs fine.

I think I am missing some quotes someplace and I have tried various combinations with no luck.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions @PhilDW.

I could possibly take out the cmd jacket and just run the exe and try.

I finally got it working though, by changing some quotes etc. Here's what the final FileName & Command Line argument looks like:

*"[SystemFolder]cmd.exe" /c start "" /d"C:\Program Files (x86)\foldername\" "somefile.exe" "%r" "%keyname=something" "%keydll=something.dll" "%appexe=C:\Program Files (x86)\otherfilename.exe"*

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

You should post the verbose MSI log section relating to this because it should show the complete resolved command line, assuming that you have created a full verbose log and not a partial log.

It's not clear why you need to run this program with a cmd jacket. If it's a plain Windows program just run the executable as a custom action.

When you run from the interactive user explorer shell you get some infrastructure (such as working directory) that you do not get with a custom action started by an msiexec.exe process. This matters because you have not specified an explicit full path to some.dll, so it's not obvious it can find the file.

It might be useful to say something about where this custom action runs and its type. For example if it's turned into an immediate custom action (all VS custom actions are deferred) then it will fail because no files have yet been installed. Likewise, if it's deferred but somehow before the InstallFiles standard action it will fail.

All custom actions run by Visual Studio generated projects are deferred and run with the system account in a per-system "Everyone" install. If your custom action requires elevation then it must also be deferred and the MSI must show a UAC elevation dialog, because otherwise it may well run but fail with access errors. It may have become a non-elevated per user install.